# WordPress post title query is not working with special character

Tags: wordpress

This title query doesn't work, in which the post title have a special character before the title. I check the post he title. For example : -y-

Here is the code the post single page template:

```
<?php

$get_s_value = $_GET['search'];

if ($get_s_value == 'true') {

    $current_p_title = get_the_title();

    $args = array (
        'post_type'   => 'trending',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        "s"           => $current_p_title,
    );

    query_posts($args);

    if (have_posts()): the_post();

        $sahifa_trending_count = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_trending_count', 1);
        $update_count          = $sahifa_trending_count + 1;
        $last_m_date           = get_the_modified_date('Y-m-d');
        $trending_c_date       = date('Y-m-d');

        if ($last_m_date = $trending_c_date) {

            update_metadata('post', get_the_ID(), '_trending_count', $update_count);
        } else {
            update_metadata('post', get_the_ID(), '_trending_count', '1');
        }

    else:

        $create_post = array (
            'post_type'   => 'trending',
            'post_title'  => get_the_title(),
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'meta_input'  => array (
                '_trending_count' => '1',
            ),
        );

        wp_insert_post($create_post);


    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try encoding the title.

```
$create_post = array (
            'post_type'   => 'trending',
            'post_title'  => utf8_encode(get_the_title()),
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'meta_input'  => array (
                '_trending_count' => '1',
            ),
        );
```